# Send multiple values with an ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two select menus:

```
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control" size="5">
         <option value="">name1</option>
         <option value="">name2</option>
</select>

<select name="category2" id="category2" class="form-control" size="5">
         <option value="">order_item1</option>
         <option value="">order_item2</option>
</select>
```

I want to send the selected value from each select box to a server sided script (fetch.php). Therefore I create a function: `function load_data(is_category, is_category2) {}`.

Now I have the problem that only the selected value from the first category select menu (`id="category"`) gets sended to my server sided script. The selected value `id="category2"` isn´t get sended to my server sided script.

**Complete code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    load_data();

    function load_data(is_category, is_category2) {

        var dataTable = $('#product_data').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],
            "ajax": {
                url: "fetch.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    is_category: is_category,
                    is_category2: is_category2
                },
            }
        }); 
    }

   // Select Box id="category"

    $(document).on('change', '#category', function () {
        var category = $(this).val();
        $('#product_data').DataTable().destroy();
        if (category != '') {
            load_data(category);
        }
        else {
            load_data();
        }
    });
     
      // Select Box id="category2"

      $(document).on('change', '#category2', function () {
        var category2 = $(this).val();
        $('#product_data').DataTable().destroy();
        if (category2 != '') {
            load_data(category2);
        }
        else {
            load_data();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You will get a better answer if you post a little more code. Is there a <form>? is there a <button>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add event listeners for both `select` elements in order to get the value of them. Then, you should add a new parameter to the `load_data` function to get those values inside the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var category = "";
    var category2 = "";
    load_data();

    function load_data(is_category, is_category2) {
        console.log(is_category, is_category2);
        var dataTable = $('#product_data').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],
            "ajax": {
                url: "fetch.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    is_category: is_category,
                    is_category2: is_category2
                },
            }
        }); 
    }

   // Select Box id="category"

    $(document).on('change', '#category, #category2', function () {
    //console.log($(this).attr('id'), category, category2)
        if ($(this).attr('id') === "category"){
          category = $(this).val();
        }else if ($(this).attr('id') === "category2"){
          category2 = $(this).val();
        }
        // 
        $('#product_data').DataTable().destroy();
        if (category != '') {
            load_data(category, category2);
        }
        else {
            load_data();
        }
    });
     
      // Select Box id="category2"

      $(document).on('change', '#category2', function () {
        var category2 = $(this).val();
        $('#product_data').DataTable().destroy();
        if (category2 != '') {
            load_data(category, category2);
        }
        else {
            load_data();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control" size="5">
         <option value="name1">name1</option>
         <option value="name2">name2</option>
</select>

<select name="category2" id="category2" class="form-control" size="5">
         <option value="order_item1">order_item1</option>
         <option value="order_item2">order_item2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tested the script. Sadly the select boxes aren´t working as expected. If I choose a variable in the first select box in the developers console shows "undefined undefined". I´ve set up a testpage with the whole script maybe you could look over it. [link](https://wildstar-mmo.de/tabelle).

Comment: I´ve made a small adjustment `load_data(category);` and `load_data(category2);` Now the first select box works perfectly. But the second one does not. Do you have an idea? I´ve updated the code under the URL.

Comment: Did you try the updated code? I think it will solve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I´m using your updated code. Besides the both changes I didn´t changed anything. :(

Comment: It is not the updated code :) Try replacing the JS Code with the updated code. I have made few changes to the load_data() function calls.

Comment: Ok ;). Now I´ve copied your js code without any changes from my side, but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Now the front-end code works. it seems like there is an issue with your back-end code. Did you check manually whether the query works?

Comment: If I change your js code `load_data(category, category2);` to `load_data(category);` the first select box is working. I´ve updated the script so you can see it. But if I adjust the js code for the second select box to `load_data(category2);` the second box doesn´t work. I don´t think it´s a query problem.

Comment: Yes, it works in that way but to get the value of both select boxes you need to parse the values like this: `load_data(category, category2)`

Comment: I understand. I´ve changed it again. I´ve updated my initial post with the php query which I´m using at the moment. So do I have to adjust this one as well, since I don´t get any results if I use `load_data(category, category2)`

Comment: I got it to work. As you´ve expected there was a small mistake in the mysql query. Thank you.